# How to call d3.svg.line() independently?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

`lineFunction` corresponds in this example with `d3.svg.line()`. Later, however, `lineFunction` is filled as a function with a parameter `lineData`, namely a list of points with x and y coordinates. How can I bypass `lineFunction` and include the dataset directly in `d3.svg.line()`?

My approach would be to call directly on `d3.svg.line(lineData)`:

```
//The line SVG Path we draw
var lineGraph = svg.append("path")
  .attr("d", d3.svg.line(lineData)
    .x(function(d) { return d.x; })
    .y(function(d) { return d.y; })
    .interpolate('linear'))
  .attr("stroke", "blue")
  .attr("stroke-width", 2)
  .attr("fill", "none");
```

But this does not make any sense, as long as this is no function, that accepts parameters. I've also looked into the D3 code base and found that the line function does accept an input:

```
export default function() {
  var x = pointX,
  // ...
  function line(data) {
    // ...
  }
  // ...
  return line;
}
```

Here is a **running example** by [Dimitar Danailov](https://bl.ocks.org/dimitardanailov):

```js
var width = 400;
var height = 400;

var svg = d3.select('body').append('svg');
svg.attr('width', width);
svg.attr('height', height);

//This is the accessor function we talked about above
var lineFunction = d3.svg.line()
  .x(function(d) { return d.x; })
  .y(function(d) { return d.y; })
  .interpolate('linear');

//The data for our line
var lineData = [ 
  { "x": 1,   "y": 5},  
  { "x": 20,  "y": 20},
  { "x": 40,  "y": 10}, 
  { "x": 60,  "y": 40},
  { "x": 80,  "y": 5},  
  { "x": 100, "y": 60}
];
  
//The line SVG Path we draw
var lineGraph = svg.append("path")
  .attr("d", lineFunction(lineData))
  .attr("stroke", "blue")
  .attr("stroke-width", 2)
  .attr("fill", "none");
```

```css
svg {
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica;
}

.line {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #000;
  stroke-width: 2px;
}
```

```html
<script src="//d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
```

Source: https://bl.ocks.org/dimitardanailov/6f0a451d4457b9fa7bf6e0dddcd0f468

Further examples: https://www.dashingd3js.com/svg-paths-and-d3js

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you can do is call `d3.svg.line()` after you've configured it, like:

```
var lineGraph = svg.append("path")
  .attr("d", d3.svg.line()
    .x(function(d) { return d.x; })
    .y(function(d) { return d.y; })
    .interpolate('linear')(lineData))
```

So the revised snippet looks like this:

```js
var width = 400;
var height = 400;

var svg = d3.select('body').append('svg');
svg.attr('width', width);
svg.attr('height', height);


//The data for our line
var lineData = [ 
  { "x": 1,   "y": 5},  
  { "x": 20,  "y": 20},
  { "x": 40,  "y": 10}, 
  { "x": 60,  "y": 40},
  { "x": 80,  "y": 5},  
  { "x": 100, "y": 60}
];
  
//The line SVG Path we draw
var lineGraph = svg.append("path")
  .attr("d", d3.svg.line()
  .x(function(d) { return d.x; })
  .y(function(d) { return d.y; })
  .interpolate('linear')(lineData))
  .attr("stroke", "blue")
  .attr("stroke-width", 2)
  .attr("fill", "none");
```

```css
svg {
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica;
}

.line {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #000;
  stroke-width: 2px;
}
```

```html
<script src="//d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
```

**Edit:** Note that the question and answer uses `d3.svg.line()` which is from d3 v3. For higher versions you can use `d3.line()`, and omit the `interpolate`, like that mentioned below by @uzay95.

Comment: But can you explain why a variable changes to a function? And why I cannot call that function directly?

Comment: From the way d3 is designed, calling d3.svg.line() always returns a function (which can be further configured with .x(), .y() etc). Instead of being designed for the use case you have in mind, it uses a function-heavy philosophy. You can read more about it at https://bost.ocks.org/mike/chart

Comment: instead of ```interpolate()``` you should use ```.curve(d3.curveLinear)``` like this:

```var lineGraph = svg.append("path")
  .attr("d", d3.svg.line()
  .x(function(d) { return d.x; })
  .y(function(d) { return d.y; })
  .curve(d3.curveLinear)(lineData))```

Comment: @uzay95, this question was written for d3v3, which doesn't have `d3.curveLinear`, but I've updated my answer to include your response. Thanks!